# PHP: alternate ways to generate json?

Tags: php, json

Im working and new how to generate json on arrays in php. is there any alternate ways or best way to generate json on php?

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
<?php
$array = 
        array(

        'name' =>  

        array(

        'gender'=> 'male-female', 
        'location' => 'adress here'), 

        'age' => 'age here',

        'about me' => array(array(
        'birthday' => 'MM-DD-YYYY', 
        'status' => 'status here', 
        'childrens' => 'childrens here')), 

        'employer' => array('bank','fastfood','sales'), 

        'nameofchildrens' => array(array(
        'name1' => "namehere1" , 'employer2' => array('bank','fastfood','sales'), 
        'name2' => "namehere2" , 'employer1' => array('bank','fastfood','sales'))),

        'relatives' => array(),

        'siblings' => array(),

        'ancestors' => array(),

        'pets' => array(array('dog','cat','rabbit')),

        'sports' => array('basketball','badminton','volleyball'),

        );

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

This how I generate a json with format I wanted. It's working but is there anyone can provide me a alternate ways to generate a json format like this?

OUTPUT:

```
{"name":{"gender":"male-female","location":"adress here"},"age":"age here","about me":[{"birthday":"MM-DD-YYYY","status":"status here","childrens":"childrens here"}],"employer":["bank","fastfood","sales"],"nameofchildrens":[{"name1":"namehere1","employer2":["bank","fastfood","sales"],"name2":"namehere2","employer1":["bank","fastfood","sales"]}],"relatives":[],"siblings":[],"ancestors":[],"pets":[["dog","cat","rabbit"]],"sports":["basketball","badminton","volleyball"]}
```

Comment: Well, cleaner maybe using `[]` [notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead of `array()`.  That and being a stickler with indentation!

Comment: Aside from just writing it in pure JSON in the first place? No.

Comment: You could make a Person class and then run json_encode on the object.

Comment: @Karl can you provide me an example

Comment: See this if you are using PHP 5.4+: http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Answer (score 2):

You could make a class an run json_encode() on the object.

```
<?php
class Person {
    public $name;
    public $age;
}
$person = new Person();
$person->name = 'Foo';
$person->age = 22;

echo json_encode($person);
```

This is in it's simpliest form, so if you havan't read up on classes and objects I suggest you do.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: i tried this before but it dont let me the format of the json i want. like when I add some array().

Comment: The trouble with using `json_encode()` on objects is that it will only encode the public attributes, private attrs get skipped.

Comment: PHP has a magic method for [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) but nothing similar for arrays/JSON.  You can write a `toJSON()` method that spits back a representation of the object as you desire it and call it. `json_encode($obj->toJSON())`.   Be sure to read that [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) from the answer.

Comment: @ficuscr can you give me an example for that

Answer (score 1):

I found this way but it doesnt let me to the format I wanted.

```
<?php
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->metadata = "Devices per year";
    $obj->data = array(
        array('1999','3.0'),
        array('2000','3.9'),
        //and so on...
    );

    echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people used Zend_Json before because of common native PHP json errors. But there's no difference at all.

My personal favourite is JMS/Serializer which serializes arrays and objects using metadata maps or using annotations. As long as you have some Entity / DAO representation you can simply define (un)serilalizing schema and just serialize objects or object collections without defining custom arrays.

Documentation: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Github: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer